# ThreadAbortException on debugging

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, visual-studio

I am using this way to execute async void methods with access to local variables:

```
static void RunAsync(object var1, object var2)
{
    ThreadStart work = delegate
    {
        try
        {
            Statement1(var1);
            Statement2(var2);
            // etc
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
    };
    new Thread(work).Start();
}
```

Debugging through unit test in Visual Studio often causes `ThreadAbortException`, but running tests (and running code) works fine.

What is causing this?

Comment: Could you get some info from the Exception?

Comment: not really: http://monosnap.com/image/w8jY9nRAonveWBrP7VfTssWp8/

Comment: Debug + Exceptions, untick the Thrown checkbox.

Comment: Unit tests do not involve threading. You've misunderstood the concept of a unit test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because when you call RunAsync method it creates the thread but returns to TestMethod where the test finishes before the thread finishes. When the test finishes it tries to abort all the threads so you get that exception. You must wait until the thread finishes by using a Join.

Suggestion:

```
Thread t;
static void RunAsync(object var1, object var2)
{
    ThreadStart work = delegate
    {
        try
        {
            Statement1(var1);
            Statement2(var2);
            // etc
        }
        catch (Exception e) { }
    };
    t=new Thread(work);
    t.Start();
}
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod()
{
   RunAsync();

   DoOtherStuff();
   if(t!=null)
      t.Join();

}
```

Comment: Won't this eliminate the very purpose of `RunAsync` method? As I understand the question the tests are made async to be ran in parallel. To put your suggestion to practise the `RunAsync` should return `Thread` instance started. And the test runner should collect all the `Thread` instances to a list and then wait for them all to complete. The task is more straightforward using `TPL` and `Task`: `Task.WaitAll(tasks)`

Comment: Yeah, somthing like that, but more flexible to handle multiple async tests. (btw I am not the questioneer)