# Thread Abort when debugging azure worker role

Tags: azure, debugging, visual-studio-2015, azure-worker-roles, azure-compute-emulator

If waiting for too long (*a minute or more*) on a breakpoint,
I can't continue as thread is being aborted. Thus I need to constantly "step over" or do other actions for any code to run, or else I get thread aborted.

This really is frustrating. Is there any way to change this behavior/timeout?

Comment: To change the timeout, you can try changing some of the Timeouts in the above registry key, and restart Visual Studio: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787334/how-to-keep-visual-studio-debugger-visualizers-from-timing-out. Besides, you can check following threads if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304752/how-to-debug-a-single-thread-in-visual-studio and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378707/threadabortexception-on-debugging

Comment: Thanks for suggestion to look into registry, but I did not found anything connected to _Azure Compute Emulator_. Timeout itself occurs not in _Visual Studio_, but rather from _Compute Emulator_ that initiates _Thread Abort_